# Django 3 template date tag return nothing

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm try to use date template tag to format datetime from database

```
2020-10-23 08:59:44.792274
```

on django template

```
{{ item.payment_received_time }} # return 2020-10-23 08:59:44.792274
{{ item.payment_received_time|date:"D d M Y" }} # return nothing
```

but nothing is returned, what am I missing on it ?
Thanks

Comment: Likely this is because `payment_received_time` is a **string**, not a `datetime`. Did you use a `DateTimeField` in the database?

Comment: thanks, I'm use SerializerMethodField(), because in database it saved as json, but now I'm parse thath string to datetime object and works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (…) but nothing is returned.

The [**`|date`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) only works on `date` and `datetime` objects. It can not process strings, since then the structure is "lost".

For example:

```
>>> Template('{{ foo|date:"D d M Y" }}').render(Context({'foo': datetime.now().date()}))
'Sun 25 Oct 2020'
>>> Template('{{ foo|date:"D d M Y" }}').render(Context({'foo': '2020-10-25'}))
```

In your models, you thus store the `payment_received_time` as a [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) or a [**`DateField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField):

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    payment_received_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, so, because I'm using SerializerMethodField, I'm use parser from dateutil to convert that string to date object